# Why do I show up as two users in reports that pull from GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: github

I'm the only one on the team that I see this problem with.  Some of my commits show my full name and others show my username.  There are no accessibility issues regarding that, I have full access to what I should no matter what it shows.  However, some of our reporting systems that reach in to pull out data see me as two different people.

Others on the team always show up as full name, even for things committed under the login name.  It's as if there's some linkage between the two that is broken just for me.  I'm not seeing anything obvious in my profile.  It's been like this as far back as I can remember too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mismatch between my local (Git profile) username and my GitHub username.  I updated my local one to match the server.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what the issue ended up being. Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different "names" you can use on GitHub -- your username and your public name.  It's possible that using different names for the two is causing some confusion somewhere internal.

Try changing your public name to match your username (see below) and see if the discrepancy still occurs.

You can change your **public name** at https://github.com/settings/profile (when you're logged in).

You can change your **username** at https://github.com/settings/admin (also when logged in).

Comment: Helpful, but this is GitHub Enterprise, not GitHub.com, plus the problem turned out to be with the CLI version of Git being wrong